# Nginx configuration error while running Rails app and Wordpress blog on same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx

I am developing a Ruby on Rails application and meanwhile I am currently using a Wordpress blog that serves as a landing page.

I am using Ruby (2.2.4) on Rails (4.2.6) on an AWS EC2 instance. I'm also using nginx, apache and puma.

The problem I ran into was the following:

```
* Restarting nginx nginx                                                  [fail]
```

And the logs are the following:

```
2016/10/25 23:54:53 [emerg] 24676#0: duplicate upstream "php" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/defaultsave:148
```

I have these two upstream configurations that read as follows (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default):

```
upstream puma {
   server unix:///home/deploy/apps/APPLICATION_NAME/shared/tmp/sockets/APPLICATION_NAME-puma.sock;
}
```

and

```
upstream php {
  server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

**Can I have two upstream configurations? How can I solve this issue?**

I also tried commenting one of the upstreams and the logs read as follows:

```
2016/10/26 00:14:22 [emerg] 25249#0: duplicate listen options for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:154
```

**Can I listen to the same port and proxy to the correct server having into account the server_name?**

Comment: Is there a backup file called `defaultsave` in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`?

Comment: Thank you for taking your time with this issue @Richard. There is a backup file called `default.save` in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` but not a  `defaultsave` one.

Comment: Ok. Nginx is reading that file too. This is causing the duplication errors. You need to remove it.

Comment: I feel silly. It was in fact that the case. Thank you very much for your help. Now I'm getting a 502 error but I think I will be able to solve it.